# Evaluate the limit of $\prod_{k=2}^n(1-\frac2{k(k+1)})^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_{n}$, where $x_{n} = (1-(1/3))^{2}(1-(1/6))^{2}(1-(1/10))^{2} \dots (1-(2/(n(n+1)))^{2}, n≥2$

I couldn't find any pattern of terms to find the limit.
I applied $\log$ both sides to get -
$\log x_{n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} 2\sum_{k=1}^{n} \log (1-(2/(k(k+1))$

Then I am stuck.

I also tried this -

$x_{n} = [(2/3)(5/6)(9/10) \dots (\frac{n(n+1)-2}{n(n+1)})]^{2}$
But, I am finding nothing.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Note that $$n(n+1)-2=(n-1)(n+2)$$ hence $$\left(1-\frac2{n(n+1)}\right)^2=\frac{(n-1)^2(n+2)^2}{n^2(n+1)^2}$$ In view of the above, I am surprised that you "couldn't find any pattern" in the partial products... Maybe a new look at these could help?

Comment: In an old notebook i have found this here $$\frac{1}{9}\left(\frac{n+2}{n}\right)^2$$

Comment: we have proved it via induction.

Comment: Who needs "old notebooks" here when the cancellations are so visible?

Comment: @Did I got the pattern $x_{n} = (\frac{1(4)}{2(3)} \frac{2(5)}{3(4)} \frac{3(6)}{4(5)} \dots )^{2}$ by applying limit $n \to \infty$, I got $1/9$

Answer (score 1):

$$\prod_{k=2}^n\left(1-\frac2{k(k+1)}\right)^2{=\prod_{k=2}^n\left({k(k+1)-2\over k(k+1)}\right)^2\\=\left(\prod_{k=2}^n{k(k+1)-2\over k(k+1)}\right)^2\\=\left(\prod_{k=2}^n{(k-1)(k+2)\over k(k+1)}\right)^2\\=\left(\prod_{k=2}^n{k-1\over k}\right)^2\left(\prod_{k=2}^n{k+2\over k+1}\right)^2\\=\left({1\over n}\right)^2\left({n+2\over 3}\right)^2\\={n^2+4n+4\over 9n^2}}$$therefore $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\prod_{k=2}^n\left(1-\frac2{k(k+1)}\right)^2={1\over 9}$$